# how to merge two classification models (tensorflow, keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have two simple Image-classification models, and both have same input shape.
my goal is to merge both models so that I don't need to use them separately.

[I tried this sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669876/how-to-merge-two-models-in-keras-tensoflow-to-make-one-model.). but it does not work

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 50, 50, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 25, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1152)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               147584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================
Total params: 203,874
Trainable params: 203,874
Non-trainable params: 0
________________________________________
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 50, 50, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 25, 25, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 25, 25, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1152)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               147584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 258       
=================================================================
Total params: 203,874
Trainable params: 203,874
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Architecture is the same for both models.
I want to merge them, so I just need to pass the image in it and it will come up with the right prediction out of 4.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is not really possible, just train a model with four classes. The problem is that in a classical NN, the confidences do not tell you if the model is wrong or not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. is there any other way to find an "unknown" class? after I train the model.

Comment: May be you need to add one class called "unknown" for which it does not fall under any other category. Thanks